# Did the Israelites not outgrow their clothes in the forty year wanderings?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, moses

It is said according to Deuteronomy the Israelites wondered in the wilderness for forty years without their clothing and sandals wearing out.

Deuteronomy 29:5 NASB

***5 And I have led you in the wilderness for forty years; your clothes have not worn out on you, and your sandal has not worn out on your foot***.

But in those forty years wondering in the wilderness some had been young and now they were old so could they not have outgrown their clothing

Comment: Having clothes/sandals that don't wear out doesn't prevent you from making **new** clothes/sandals.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator - I agree - it simply means you do not need to replace worn out clothes.

Comment: They had spoiled the Egyptians, before leaving Egypt, borrowing what they would need. _And the LORD gave the people favour in the sight of the Egyptians, so that they lent unto them such things as they required. And they spoiled the Egyptians._ Exodus 12:36.

Comment: Another point to consider is that as the families grew in stature, their outgrown clothes would be given to the younger generation, aka "hand-me-downs".

Comment: One also needs to account for population increase. Over 40 years, Israel could easily have doubled or quadrupled in numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did the Israelites not outgrow their clothes in the forty year wanderings?

Yes, some did but God provided miraculously.

Deuteronomy 8:

> 2Remember how the Lord your God led you all the way in the wilderness these forty years, to humble and test you in order to know what was in your heart, whether or not you would keep his commands. 3He humbled you, causing you to hunger and then feeding you with manna, which neither you nor your ancestors had known, to teach you that man does not live on bread alone but on every word that comes from the mouth of the Lord. 4Your clothes **did not wear out** and your feet **did not swell** during these forty years.

They always had good clothes on their back and good shoes on their feet because God miraculously provided as he did for their food. They didn't have any trouble finding materials to make new clothes or shoes when needed.

Deuteronomy 29:5

> the LORD says, "During the forty years that I led you through the wilderness, your clothes did not wear out, nor did the sandals on your feet.

Ezekiel 16:10 gives us some idea of what sandals were made of:

> I clothed you with an embroidered dress and put sandals of fine leather on you.

God miraculously preserved their old clothes and sandals and provided materials for making new clothes and sandals.
The 40 years in the wilderness was one big lesson in God's providence.

Comment: They had spoiled the Egyptians, before leaving Egypt, borrowing what they would need. _And the LORD gave the people favour in the sight of the Egyptians, so that they lent unto them such things as they required. And they spoiled the Egyptians._ Exodus 12:36.

Comment: I modified and added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having clothes/sandals that don't wear out doesn't prevent you from making **new** clothes/sandals. To illustrate the point by way of an analogy: if there is a store that sells indestructible clothing, and you buy some for your newborn son, but months later he outgrows his clothes, well, you simply go to the store and buy him some new indestructible clothes again. I do not see where the problem is.

Comment: There were no stores in the wilderness, is the problem. And the enemies didn't trade. Hence the manna from heaven. And hence the preservation of what clothing they had when they left Egypt. If you just 'go to the store' then why is the clothing preserved in the first place ? Your answer is illogical.

Comment: There sure are a lot of instructions on making things out of textiles in the wilderness for a people you assume can't make anything... Upvoted.

Comment: @NigelJ - I meant that part as an analogy, not literally. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Justin Martyr's *Dialogue with Trycho* chapter 131, he claims that childrens' clothing grew with them. It was a miracle. He says,

> The latches of your shoes did not break, and your shoes grew not old, and your garments wore not away, but even those of children grew along with them.

I don't necessarily believe this, but the earliest church did.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).